# assembly load error

Tags: .net

I receive

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'DeployLX.Licensing.v3,
>   Version=3.1.2000.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=798276055709c98a' or
>   one of its dependencies. One or more
>   arguments are invalid (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80000003) InnerException:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

On some copiers of windows vista 32bit. The file is there it seems like the copy of vista is missing a native dependency. Any ideas how to find a managed assemblies native dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the assembly is a COM wrapper.

In that case, you can load it into [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and look at the ComImport GUID attribute, which will tell you the class ID of the control that could most likely not be found.

You will have to look that GUID up on another computer where it works in the registry to get the name of the .dll you need (to regsvr32). Or ask Google...

Comment: That would make sense, I could see name not found errors in procmon log file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when working with Umbraco CMS. Turns out if you're running a 64-bit OS, there's a small setting adjustment you have to make to allow 32-bit mode worker processes:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:true
```

Answer taken from [here](http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst7623_DeployLXLicensingv3-Error-when-moving-Umbraco-to-a-64bit-host.aspx)